# how to throw exception at compile time in java

Tags: java

I need to throw exception at compile time itself..for example if i have 3 files in my project folder instead of 4 files.While  compiling project it has to throw exception.. what to do please help me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of explaining the details in depth, I will just say **This is not possible.** But If you can actually explain why you want to do it then we can provide alternate ways to meet your requirement.

Comment: If one was using ant or some type of build tool couldn't it assert for the existence of specific files?

Comment: The build tool could, but the java program itself can't.

Comment: Custom annotation processors make this possible. They are a good solution for this question, but probably not for its asker.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply sir.. I need to develop a project for installation application..In this i need to keep 3 or more files for key if there is a lose of number of files i need to catch the exception at time of building the project itself. for that purpose only i raise this question..

Comment: as others have suggested build tools are appropriate for this. Are you using Ant or Maven? How are you building the project? What is the out come of the build i.e a jar or war or ear?

Comment: I am not well versed with Ant. I think you have to write a custom ant Pre-Process task that will check the number of files and will fail the build using "Fail" task. Look here on how to write a custom ant task http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html. If you are not sure on how to start then post a new question here seeking help

Answer (score 3):

That's not part of Java, it depends on your development tools. The language can't help you with that.